# ngx-select-dropdown example value not binding

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

can any one give example for     ngx-select-dropdown  value and options array  example

```
<ngx-select-dropdown [config]="config" [options]="dropdownOptions" 
                           [(value)]="dataModel" [multiple]="false" ></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ngx-select-dropdown (change)="selectionChanged($event)" [multiple]="true" [(value)]="dataModel" [config]="config" [options]="dropdownOptions"></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

in here **dataModel** means bonded array ID or some attribute. **dropdownOptions** like Your array Name refer this [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-dropdown). Use **`[(value)] ==>[(ngModel)]`** and you need to `dataModel : any` in ts file.